# Keep the phone screen ON in Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++11, cocos2d-x

I created a game for Android using Cocos2DX 3.4. I'm using the acelerometer for the player to move around the screen so I don't need to touch the screen. The problem is that the screen turn off when I play for a while. I need to know how to keep the phone awake even if I don't touch the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution, but I´m still waiting for a better one if any:

Just added this to my CPP:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
#include "../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxHelper.h"
#endif
```

Then I added this init method to my main Scene:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !LayerColor::initWithColor( Color4B(204,204,204,255)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    setKeepScreenOnJni(true);
    #endif
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Since version 3.3, there is setKeepScreenOn method, which can be used to keep the screen bright: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.4/d7/df0/classcocos2d_1_1_device.html#a6939889f4a5f4b2581979e126a99bc77

Comment: But under the hood it uses the same method as you used above: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/platform/android/CCDevice-android.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Just Write

```
cocos2d::Device::setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

on the First Scene you load.